# Tomcat on Windows

Tags: tomcat, service, procrun

I installed Tomcat 6.0.18 on Windows 2003 as a service.

I try to set the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable but it seems to be ignored by Tomcat. 
Do I need to use the Tomcat Service Manager (procrun) instead?

Is it normal that if I install Tomcat as a service it doesn't see the enviroment variables but it only wotks with procrun?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes (procrun).  Tomcat as a Windows service is a bit of voodoo to me, but that's how I accomplished modifying the options .

Open up regedit and navigate to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Apache Software Foundation > Procrun 2.0 > Tomcat[x] > Parameters > Java

You'll see Options there.  Those are probably technically JAVA_OPTS, but they'll still be passed on to Tomcat.

Comment: Does it mean that the "traditional" CATALINA environment variables do not have any effect?